# 'Wit' object has no attribute 'message'

Tags: python-2.7, wit.ai

Just trying to experiment with Wit.ai & Python but getting the following error. What am I doing wrong here??

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python27/mx1.py", line 7, in <module>
resp = client.message(my_message)
AttributeError: 'Wit' object has no attribute 'message'
```

Code:

```
from wit import Wit
access_token='B3GHXHLTXIASO7S4KY7UC65LMSTCDEHK'
client = Wit(access_token)
my_message='who are you?'
resp = client.message(my_message)
print(resp)
```

Comment: Your example is working just fine for me (response contains `I am Jarvis`), but I'm on Linux. Could you tell us how exactly did you install the Wit library?

Comment: I am running Python 2.7 on Win10. I installed using "pip install pywit".

Comment: The [docs](https://github.com/wit-ai/pywit#install) say `pip install wit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it seems like you're using an older (actually [unofficial](https://github.com/lextoumbourou/PyWit)) version of the Python [`pywit` package, last updated on 2015-11-07 (version 0.4.0)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyWit).

You should remove the `pywit` package and install `wit`, just like they say in the [docs/install](https://github.com/wit-ai/pywit#install) section:

```
pip uninstall pywit
pip install wit
```

Just for completeness, if you look inside the `wit.py` of your older `pywit` package, inside your `python2.7/site-packages/wit/wit.py`, you'll see the definition of old `Wit` class, with a `get_message()` method instead of the current `message()`. So, in the `pywit`, your code will run if you say:

```
resp = client.get_message(my_message)
```

instead of

```
resp = client.message(my_message)
```

But you should really switch to the current (official) version.