# Wit AI message API

Tags: python, json, nlp, wit.ai

Can someone please let me know how to make requests to Wit.ai message api. I am struggling with my code.

```
import requests
import json
import sys
from wit import Wit


# Wit speech API endpoint
API_ENDPOINT = 'https://api.wit.ai/message'

q='who are you'

# Wit.ai api access token
wit_access_token = 'B3GHXHLTXIASO7S4KY7UC65LMSTCDEHK'

    # defining headers for HTTP request
headers = {'authorization': 'Bearer ' + wit_access_token}

    # making an HTTP post request
resp = requests.post(API_ENDPOINT, headers = headers,data = {'q':'who are you'})

    # converting response content to JSON format
data = json.loads(resp.content)

print(data)
```

I am getting back this:

```
{u'code': u'json-parse', u'error': u'Invalid JSON'}
```

Comment: Try writing Authorization with capital A. Also send it as a .get. According to their docs you don't need a .post. So with that done call it like this: resp = requests.get(API_ENDPOINT, headers=headers, params={'q': 'who are you'}).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`/message`](https://wit.ai/docs/http/20170307#get--message-link) endpoint of Wit API accepts only `GET` method and expects the query parameters in URL (not `data` in request body). The `requests` library will correct the case on your lowercase `Authorization` header field, but it's a good practice to write it according to [the standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.2). Also, JSON response can be fetched decoded with `json()` method on `Response`.

With all of this:

```
import requests

API_ENDPOINT = 'https://api.wit.ai/message'
WIT_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'B3GHXHLTXIASO7S4KY7UC65LMSTCDEHK'

headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(WIT_ACCESS_TOKEN)}
query = {'q': 'who are you'}

resp = requests.get(API_ENDPOINT, headers=headers, params=query)
data = resp.json()

print(data)
```

Note however, Wit has a [Python library](https://github.com/wit-ai/pywit) which abstracts all of these low-level details, and makes your code much simpler and easier to read. Use it.

It would look like this ([example](https://github.com/wit-ai/pywit#wit-class) from the docs):

```
from wit import Wit
client = Wit(access_token=WIT_ACCESS_TOKEN)
resp = client.message('what is the weather in London?')
print('Yay, got Wit.ai response: ' + str(resp))
```

Comment: Tried using the below code but still getting error

    from wit import Wit
    WIT_ACCESS_TOKEN =  'B3GHXHLTXIASO7S4KY7UC65LMSTCDEHK'
    client = Wit(WIT_ACCESS_TOKEN)
    resp = client.message('who are you?')
    print('Yay, got Wit.ai response: ' + str(resp))

Got:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Python27/wit_try.py", line 4, in <module>
    resp = client.message('who are you?')
    AttributeError: 'Wit' object has no attribute 'message'

Comment: I tested the first code sample above (with requests lib), that works for sure. The second sample I (mostly) copied from their documentation example, and haven't tested it. You can try the full example they provide in the docs, please see the link from my answer.

Comment: The first code sample worked well. Thanks for that!!! I also first tried using the Wit message API. But the result was same as posted above. I have another question running regarding it but nobody answered yet. Can you please test it?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45121612/wit-object-has-no-attribute-message

Comment: Glad it worked. Please also consider upvoting it and closing the question by accepting the answer.

Comment: Yes definitely, can you check why the example from the docs not working, I would really like to you the example code